# Can't get async method that calls WCF service to work - async newbie

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, soap, async-await

I need to test async calls to an external SOAP service.  I have a Main program that builds requests to the web service (it will eventually become a Windows service, but keeping it simple for debug purposes).  The Main program calls the service multiple times from within a loop.  I need to build the SOAP request dynamically, so I have a class that does this and within that class I have an async method that looks like this:

```
public async Task<WebServiceResponse> ExecuteWebService()
{
     var request = BuildRequest(); //non-async: builds dynamic SOAP request
     var retrieveDataClient = new ExternallyProvidedInterfaceClient();
     retrieveDataClient.Open();
     return await retrieveDataClient.RetrieveDataAsync(request);
}
```

My problem is this:  When I debug the method above, it returns as soon as the external client constructor is called (second line).  The Open() method is never called and the actual SOAP call is never made.

I'm new to async programming...can someone show me where I went wrong and explain why the method returns BEFORE it reaches the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

My stupid.  I ran SvcUtil on a service that had already provided an InterfaceClient.  This created a local copy of the client.  When I executed the constructor, it was getting confused between the two.  Deleted the local copy of the InterfaceClient class and all is well.